# How to check HOW a browser is online

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I know the online status could be checked using the javascript API navigator.onLine.

However, for smartphone html5 apps it would be also interesting HOW the online has been set.
Either by WLAN or using 3G/4G connection.

Is there a way to detect the kind of online connection?

Comment: I spend a couple of hours a day connected to a WLAN with a router that connects to the Internet via 3G…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.navigator.connection` but the support for this API is very limited at the moment. Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.connection